# FLEX: how can I cut the strings longer than N characters

Tags: apache-flex

what's the easiest way to cut string in Flex ?
I mean, I have a sequence of urls, I want them at most 60 characters length. If they are longer they should be cut and "..." should be added at the end.

```
<mx:LinkButton label="{bookmarksRepeater.currentItem.name}" click="navigateToURL(new URLRequest(event.currentTarget.label.toString()))" />
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can run full flex code in the label="" section, perhaps set the label to this:
it's a conditional statement: if the name length is less than or equal to 60, just use the name, otherwise use the first 57 characters of the name and '...'

```
bookmarksRepeater.currentItem.name.length <= 60 ? bookmarksRepeater.currentItem.name : bookmarksRepeater.currentItem.name.substr(0, 57) + '...'
```

Comment: how can I run full flex code ? I tried label="{bookmarksRepeater.currentItem.name.length <= 60 ? bookmarksRepeater.currentItem.name : bookmarksRepeater.currentItem.name.substr(0, 57) + '...'}" but it gives me this error: The value of attribute "label" must not contain the '<' character.

Answer (score 1):

`substr(startIndex:Number = 0, len:Number = 0x7fffffff):String`
Returns a substring consisting of the characters that start at the specified startIndex and with a length specified by len.

from [HERE](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/String.html)